# Running simple unit test in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nunit

I am trying to run a series of simple unit test, trying to test some simple functions in my scripts. These functions are not related to my gameobjects and are only created to trim some strings.
Whenever i try to run my test i get this error.

CommandReaderTest is inconclusive

2021.04.29 16:02:39.614    WARN Element Assets.Scripts.Test.CommandReaderTest.CommandReader_RemoveInput_ReturnsShortenString was left pending after its run completion.

```
[TestFixture]
public class CommandReaderTest
{
    ICommandReader commandReader;

    [SetUp]
    public void setup()
    {
        commandReader = new CommandReader();
    }

    [Test]
    public void CommandReader_RemoveInput_ReturnsShortenString()
    {
        //Arrange 
        var inputString = "if(wall==true){CharacterJump()}if(hole==true) 
        {CharacterJump()}if(wall==true){CharacterCrouch()}";
        var trim = "if(wall==true)";

        //Act
        var shortenString = commandReader.TrimEnd(trim, inputString);
        
        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(inputString.Length - trim.Length, shortenString.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element in unit tests left pending after completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764422/element-in-unit-tests-left-pending-after-completion)

Comment: Not really since resharper is working in other solutions

Comment: Is `CommandReader` a MonoBehaviour? .. in this case please refer to [this](https://imgur.com/a/cxXXMgb)!

Comment: No it is not. This is my class definition public class CommandReader : ICommandReader. CommandReader is a simple class meant to trim a string.

Comment: What test runner are you using? Are any tests in this project/solution working, or all show that same error? Can you reproduce in a fresh project? (I can't reproduce.)